# Solr / Lucene - is buildOnCommit for DirectSolrSpellChecker (SpellCheck component)

Tags: solr, lucene, search-engine

Just want to know if `buildOnCommit` is allowed (or needed) for `DirectSolrSpellChecker` in the `SpellCheck component`.

Also, if someone could point out an "**active**" lucene/solr forum, it would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[buildOnCommit](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent#Building_on_Commits) is allowed for [DirectSolrSpellChecker](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent#Custom_Comparators_and_the_Lucene_Spell_Checkers_.28IndexBasedSpellChecker.2C_FileBasedSpellChecker.2C_DirectSolrSpellChecker.29), however is not mandatory or needed.

Documentation :-

> NOTE: Building on commit is very expensive and is discouraged for most
>   production systems. For large indexes, one commit may take minutes
>   since the building of spellcheck dictionary is single threaded. Use
>   buildOnOptimize or explicit build instead.

The Solr/Lucene group is very active and you can find the Mailing list and IRC [here](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/discussion.html).

Comment: thanks a lot.. is there any user-friendly (like a proper forum or stackexchange) for Lucene / Solr?

Comment: nope .. but the user list is very active and have the committers answering as well.